# ruby on rails - NameError in Images#show, undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x007f2179a53d30>:0x007f2174b50238>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to use CarrierWave to allow users to upload images. Right now I'm simply trying to display the image after upload, but after hitting the submit button I get the 'undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x007f2179a53d30>:0x007f2174b50238>' error shown in the title.

Here's my images_controller:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new
    if @image.save
      redirect_to @image
    end
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

and my image.rb (model):

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

new.html.erb (the upload form):

```
<%= form_for @image, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb (the page throwing the error):

```
<%= image_tag image.image_url %>
```

And to show that the 'image' column is present in my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160319135740) do

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Honestly I have no idea what the problem might be. According to every tutorial I've read image_url should work but it isn't finding the method.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: where are you saving image ? you are only creating new instance @image = Image.new

Comment: I have @image.save in my controller

Comment: are you string images locally or s3?

Comment: Just locally. It's only a test application right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @image = Image.new
      end

      def create
        @image = Image.new(image_params) ##assign image params here
        if @image.save
          redirect_to @image
        end
      end

      def show
        @image = Image.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end


     private
       def image_params
         params.require(:image).permit(:image)
       end

    end
```

and in `show.html.erb`

```
 <%= image_tag @image.image_url %>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!